# Update value of range using localStorage Angular

Tags: angularjs, range, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm trying to update the value of a range input in Angular, using `localStorage`.

This is what I have in my HTML:

```
input type="range" id="myRange" value={{audio.volume}}  min="0" max="1" step="0.01" ng-model="audio.volume" ng-change="adjustVolume()"
```

I want the value of the range to be dynamic.

And this is my js:

```
$scope.adjustVolume = function (){ 
  localStorageService.set("volume",$scope.audio.volume);
}
```

This way I manage to save the key "volume" in `localStorage`, but if I refresh the page the position of the slider of the range is back at 1, even though the `localStorage` is still set to some other number.

How can I keep the value of the range same as the value from `localStorage`, and also the position of the range.

Comment: What is $scope.audio.volume initially set to in your controller? You are likely not defining it based on the local storage value when the controller loads.

Comment: at page load I do this check

                 if (localStorageService.get("volume") == null){
                  localStorageService.set("volume","1");}

                 else{
                     localStorageService.set("volume",$scope.audio.volume);

                 }

because  i want if the key volume in localStorage doesnt exist, the value of the range to be 1, and if it already exists to be the value of the localStorage.

Comment: If that's your actual code then the logic is "if localStorageService.get("volume") is not null then set localStorageService value for 'volume' to $scope.audio.volume". Assuming that at this stage $scope.audio.volume has no value the logic simply says "if there's a value in localStorage then set it to null". Try replacing your code with following: if (localStorageService.get("volume") == null){ localStorageService.set("volume","1");}; $scope.audio = $scope.audio || {}; $scope.audio.volume = localStorageService.get("volume");

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you initialise your scope properties inside the controller you need to assign the value of $scope.audio.volume using the value from localStorage.
for example:

```
$scope.audio.volume = localStorageService.get("volume");
```

But this will only work if you already initialised the property "audio". If the volume is the only property of "audio" you want to initialise then your initialisation should look like this:

```
$scope.audio = {'volume':localStorageService.get("volume")};
```

So an example of the controller would look like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyAudioController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.audio = {'volume':localStorageService.get("volume")};//<--THIS IS IMPORTANT
  $scope.adjustVolume = function (){ 
     localStorageService.set("volume",$scope.audio.volume);
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I do this to set the value of volume in localStorage

localStorageService.set("volume",$scope.audio.volume);

and it saves it, my problem is that when i refresh the page the value of the range is back to 1. and  i want it to be same as the value from localStorage

Comment: Sorry, I used "set" method of the localStorage instead of "get" in my original answer. I updated it - hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using the watch function, which updates the value every time there is a change.

```
         $scope.$watch(function(){
            $scope.audio.volume = localStorageService.get("volume");                
            return true;
        });
```